# Profiling node.js on Windows

Tags: node.js, profiler

Can I profile a node.js process running on Windows?

A step by step guide or a link to a blog post would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone else runs into the same problem:

- get the source from github (select the required branch)
- use cygwin and python from the chromium source http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/deps/third_party
- use VS C++ Express 2010 (at least for v0.8)
- target the 32bit release (I couldn't get x64 to work)
- build node and v8
- move the v8 exe's from the build directory to v8

Run node with "node --prof source.js" and then analyze the v8.log with "windows-tick-processor.bat"

If you get too many "unaccounted" ticks you did something wrong.

Comment: Is there any simpler way?